# Wordpress: Multiple Search Criteria on Custom Fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-fields

I'm just an basic Wordpress user. I need to make search box with **multiple criteria** inputs (multiple conditions) to search **inside various Custom Fields**.

For example including following **Custom Fields**:

Color: ***_*___**
Size: **__*_*_**
Price: ***_*__**
Condition: **__*_***
Discount %: ***_*__**
Hit Count: **__*_***

User may input **1 or more** fileds.
Result should be filtered for multiple input also.
So, how can i handle this multiple conditions in Query?

It is **ok for every single inputs**.
But, problem with more then 1.
I'm confusing how to write query **for multiple criteria** (in former way).

A simple sample please.

Comment: this should be in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample query for you, just to give you an idea how to write your query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_pelleresuser` WHERE `status`=1";

if(isset($profile) && !empty($profile))
{
    $length_profile = explode(',',$profile);
    for($i=0;$i<count($length_profile);$i++)
    {
        $query.= " AND FIND_IN_SET('".$length_profile[$i]."',profile_type)"; 
    }
}

if(isset($name) && !empty($name))
{
    $query.= " AND `first_name` LIKE '".$name."'"; 
}

if(isset($city) && !empty($city))
{
    $query.= " AND `city_trainer` LIKE '".$city."' OR `city_studio` LIKE '".$city."' OR `city_reseller` LIKE '".$city."'"; 
}

if(isset($state) && !empty($state))
{
    $query.= " AND `state_trainer` LIKE '".$state."' OR `state_studio` LIKE '".$state."' OR `state_reseller` LIKE '".$state."'"; 
}

if(isset($postal) && !empty($postal))
{
    $query.= " AND `postal_trainer` LIKE '".$postal."' OR `postal_studio` LIKE '".$postal."' OR `postal_reseller` LIKE '".$postal."'"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize your search page and allow the search of custom fields, you can easily achieve this. In the sample below we are using 2 custom fields. The sample is for a business directory. Each business has a custom field for its trade, and for its location city. The default wordpress search does not come with additional form fields, but you can follow this to create a custom search for your WordPress website that uses Custom Fields.

The first thing you need to do is add the additional fields to the form.

What we want to do is add two form fields for each of the values. In my case I am tracking trade and city.

So you can visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) on creating form fields.

Once you create your form fields and name them, go to your search.php file and capture the new values to a variable, $_GET['your field name'];

```
$trade = $_GET['trade'];
$city = $_GET['city'];
```

You can then pass those values to your query where key = custom field name and value = the variable –

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
array(
            'key' => business_trade,
 'value' => $trade,

        ),
        array(
            'key' => business_city,
 'value' => $city,

        )
    )
 );
```

Full code below.

```
<?php
$trade = $_GET['trade'];
$city = $_GET['city'];

if ($trade && $city) {
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
array(
            'key' => business_trade,
 'value' => $trade,

        ),
        array(
            'key' => business_city,
 'value' => $city,

        )
    )
 );
query_posts($args);
} else {
  query_posts('posts_per_page=4');
}

if ($trade && $city) { ?>
  <h3>Your Search For <?php echo $trade; ?> and <?php echo $city; ?></h3>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <?php } if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post()
             ?>

         <p class="no_percentage"><?php echo excerpt(15); ?> </p>

        <span class="readmore" ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" > <?php _e('read more');?>  </a> </span>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php else: ?>
      <p class="notice_msg"><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria.'); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```